# pattern test on position

Tags: pattern-matching

At the moment I'm using something like this to get the positions of entries of a matrix satisfying a specific value:

```
findSuit[matrix_, player_, suit_] := {suit, #} & /@ 
   Flatten[Position[matrix[[suit]], _?(# == player &)]];
```

I'd like to access the row and column in the pattern test so I can write:

```
Position[matrix, _?(# satisfies certain conditions and the row and column corresponding to # satisfies certain conditions &)]
```

Thanks! (In this case it isn't needed but for another function I need something like this. A simple for loop through the matrix is too slow. The function has to be as fast as possible since it is called a lot!)
Sample matrix:

```
{{-3, -2, -3, -3, -4, -4, -2, -3, -1}, {2, 1, 4, -2, -1, 3, -4, 
 0, -2}, {-3, -1, -2, -4, -1, -3, -1, -1, -3}, {-1, -2, -2, -4, -4, \
-4, -4, -3, -2}}
```

Each position represents a card, for example the (1,1) entry corresponds to the card with suit 1 and rank 1. matrix[[1,1]]==-3 means that player -3 has the card with suit 1 and rank 1. There are 4 players: -1,-2,-3,-4.

Comment: Please provide sample data (`matrix`) to clarify its structure and how `player` and `suit` relate to the data.

Comment: @BobHanlon Hi, thanks for your comment, I've edited the question!

Comment: Maybe you can use `MapIndexed`? E.g `Reap[MapIndexed[If[testQ[#, #2], Sow[#2]]&, data, 2]][[2, 1]]`

Comment: @MichaelE2 Seems to run way too slow :(

Comment: Hard to respond without working code.

Comment: maybe `Select[indicesSatisfyThisCondition]@
 Position[matrix, _?valuesSatisfyThisCondition]`?

Comment: @kglr Thanks, this is neat. I was already using this but it isn't very fast. I figured that I have to avoid functions like Select and Position at all costs in the calculation intensive parts. At the moment I'm trying to create lookup tables and test if that's faster, I think this is the only way. Thanks anyways!